# Pipe the output of a command to rm command

Tags: command-line

Following command prints the path of the song being played.

```
mpc | head -n 1 
songs/oldSongs/Mukesh_D/041 KANHAIYA = YAAD AAYI ADHI RAAT KO.mp3
```

Can I delete this file by modifying the command I used to print it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To answer your more general question, that's the job of `xargs` to take a list of words on standard input and convert it to a list of arguments to a command.

However, `xargs` expects the list as a space, tab and newline (and possibly more blank characters depending on the locale and xargs implementation) separated list of words where single quotes, double quotes and backslash are used to escape those separators (with varying behaviors with regards to nesting of those by different implementations of xargs).

If the input is a newline-terminated list, the [canonical way](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html#tag_20_158_16) to convert it to the format expected by xargs is to escape every character (though only, backslash, single quote, double quote, underscore (potentially), space and tab (and possibly other blanks if not in the C locale) are necessary) but newline with a backslash character, which we can do with `sed`.

```
mpc | head -n 1 | sed 's/./\\&/g' | xargs rm --
```

Note that some `xargs` implementations have a rather low limit on the maximum line length they expect on stdin, so you may want to only escape the necessary characters with those.

With GNU `xargs` at least, you don't need to do that, you can do:

```
mpc | head -n 1 | xargs -rd '\n' rm --
```

(also using the GNU specific -r option to avoid running any command if the input is empty).

Comment: To explain the `sed`: this converts "input like this" into "\i\n\p\u\t\ \l\i\k\e\ \t\h\i\s". This won't handle newlines, but will properly escape spaces and quotes. Note also that it won't handle the tags problem @ChrisDown describes in his answer.

Comment: This answer would be better for an [edit] that explained why this is necessary and what it accomplishes.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `rm -i "/path/to/music/library/$(mpc -f %file% | head -n 1)"`. However, be warned that this will break if the filename contains a newline. As the output of `mpc -f %file%` is relative to your music library path, you need to prepend it to the output.

Comment: Note that you can work around the second problem using `mpc -f %file%`. Also, the paths `mpc` outputs are relative to the music directory you've configured it to search, so you need to add that path in. For example, `rm -i "/var/lib/mpd/music/$(mpc -f %file% | head -n 1)"`

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - Great information! Will add it to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, while I think xargs is fun and all, I kind of prefer loops for this kind of thing.  Why?  Well, it gives you more flexibility... and also gives you a fairly easy way to handle spaces:

```
mpc | head -n 1 | while read filename
do
  ls -al "$filename"  # Look at the file you're deleting
  rm -i "$filename"   # Ask if you want it deleted (or not)
done
```

When you use a while loop like that, your data gets pumped into whatever variable name comes after "read"; in order to reference the variable, you then need the leading dollar sign.  The quotes are there to gracefully handle spaces, so they don't look like delimeters.  Loops like this, while less elegant than a simple one-liner, offer you more flexibility and come in crazy handy in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are able to produce NULL-terminated filenames (as e.g. `find -print0`) you can try to quote the filenames by piping it through `sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/'`, which adds the quotes at the beginning and end of a line. Note however, that in this case you need to have:

- one file per line
- no double quotes in the filenames

The advantage is, that you can pretty much arbitrarily transform the output (e.g. when you decide not to rename rather than to delete or when you need to strip parts of the output).

Answer (score 0):

If it's safe to assume you do not have files with double quotes or newlines you can do:

```
mpc | head -n 1 | sed  's/^/"/g ; s/$/"/g' | xargs rm --
```

The sed adds quotes around your file name, and xargs turns the input it gets to arguments for the command it is running (in this case, the rm command).